# Election Polls Query

Tags: c#, sql

I have SQL tables below.

```
Candidates
ID Name Position
1 Pacquio President
2 Leni    President
3 Herbert Senator
4 Tulfo   Senator
5 Marcoleta Senator

Voters
ID  Name Candidates
1  Noel 1,3,4
2 Mar   2,4,5
3 Dan.  2,4,3
```

The result should be below

```
Results
Position Name Votes
President Leni 2
President Pacquio 1
Senator Tulfo 2
Senator Herbert 1
Senator Marcoleta 1
```

What should be my SQL Query

Thanks very much
Noel

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service; you are expected to make an effort and show your current attempt and by all means ask for help with a specific problem, [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Look up how to normalize databases. You shouldn't store a comma-delimited list of foreign keys, but rather, have a cross-reference table that maps voters to candidates.

Comment: I'm thinking to create a third table below and delete candidates field in voters table to eliminate the csv delimited. I have this stored procedure to compile multiple rows to single delimited using the xml part of the select statement. so my 3rd table should be below.
table=VoteCast

Comment: additional table below which have many to many
VotersCast Table
VoterID CAndidateID
1  1
1  3
1  4
2  2
2  4
2  5
3  2
3  4
3  3

Comment: @stu, I really work hard on this today and I think I got the answer after many attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is the Final Answer]

Show the number of votes and who voted them.

```
;WITH CastedVotes(VoterID,CandidateID) as
(
SELECT ID, value  
FROM Voters  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Candidates, ',')
)
SELECT Position, C.Name, COUNT (C.Name) as Votes
, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(V.Name,'N/A')), ',') AS 
Voters
FROM CastedVotes CV 
INNER JOIN Voters V ON VoterID=V.ID
INNER JOIN Candidates C ON CandidateID=C.ID
group by Position, C.Name
ORDER BY Position, Votes DESC
```

Comment: Please do not share code as image. Please use SO built-in code formatting tools.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
;WITH CastedVotes(VoterID,CandidateID) as --using CTE
(
SELECT ID, value  
FROM Voters  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Candidates, ',')
)
SELECT DISTINCT C.NAME
, Position
, COUNT (C.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY C.ID) AS VotesCount
FROM CastedVotes CV 
INNER JOIN Voters V ON VoterID=V.ID
INNER JOIN Candidates C ON CandidateID=C.ID
ORDER BY Position, VotesCount DESC
```

Here is the answer, I want the field position first. Any Idea maybe group by

Comment: Noel, it's unclear to me if this is an answer to your question or if you're really trying to extend your question. Can you please read [ask] and make this either (1) a clear answer or (2) delete this and edit your question?

Comment: Please edit your question with this content unless this is the answer to your question.